# Django on IIS into production

Tags: django, iis

Does anyboby have (present- actual) documentation about how to configure DJango o IIS.

I have tried some tutorials on youtube but they are old and some things have changed.

THanks you very much

Comment: With the deprecation of Python on Azure App Service (Windows), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019 all Python integration bits to IIS are also obsolete. So to really save yourself from all the pains, use Linux to host your Django apps.

Comment: You can try following the guide I uploaded last month. There’s code available to follow along https://youtu.be/APCQ15YqqQ0

Answer (score 1):

1.Please install Django and Wfastcgi.py from pip command line

```
pip install wfastcgi
wfastcgi-enable
pip install Django
```

2.generate django application and ensure it can be accessed outside IIS

```
python manage.py runserver
```

3.Please create a website in IIS and create a module mapping to map wfastcgi.py and python.exe.
[image]
[image]

```
  <handlers>
            <add name="MyFastCgiModule" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe|D:\djang\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
```

4.Set Fast-CGI Settings

[image]

5.Set Appsetting

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
      <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\djang" />
      <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="HelloWorld.settings" />
    </appSettings>
```

6.Ensure Apppool identity have permission to access python folder and wfastcgi
[image]

Finally you should be able to access the application
[image]